# Mobile device - No touch event triggered for x amount of time

Tags: jquery, mobile, touch

I am working on a mobile site where I need to have a slideshow appear if there have been no touch events for say 10 seconds. I have tried a number of things but haven't quite gotten it.

This is the code I have so far:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('#slideshow').show();
    $('#slideshow').animate({
        opacity:1   
    }, 800);
}, 3000);

$('#slideshow').click(function(){
    //alert('helo');
    $('#slideshow').animate({
        opacity:0   
    }, 800, function(){
        $('#slideshow').hide();
    });

});
```

This works but I need to trigger the show and opacity animation after so many seconds of inactivity. Anyone ever done this and have a quick solution.
Thanks

**Updated Code:**

```
    var waiting = window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('#slideshow').show();
                $('#slideshow').animate({
                    opacity:1   
                }, 800);
            }, 3000);

    var activity = $(window).click();

    $(document).on('activity', function() { 
        clearTimeout(waiting); 
            waiting = window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('#slideshow').show();
                $('#slideshow').animate({
                    opacity:1   
                }, 800);
            }, 3000);
    });

    $('#slideshow').click(function(){
        $('#slideshow').animate({
            opacity:0   
        }, 800, function(){
            $('#slideshow').hide();
        });

    });
```

This isn't quite working yet... Initially it does work. The slideshow does wait 3 seconds to appear and continually gets reset if there is any activity but one the slideshow has appeared and then been removed it doesn't reappear...?

Any ideas
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Define "activity" and whenever "activity" is triggered, have it clear the setTimeout, then initiate it again.

```
var waiting = window.setTimeout(function(){ });
$(document).on('activity', (function() { 
    clearTimeout(waiting); 
    waiting = window.setTimeout(function(){ });
});
```

Comment: This is great. I'm still not clear on how to set activity. Can you help me define inactivity based on any touch event.

Comment: FYI there is a paren in your code that throws an error. The function just after 'activity'